# MySQL LEFT JOIN columns are null

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join

I am trying to make it so that this query below counts rows from another table that have the username. There is 1 row per username in the stats table, but multiple rows with in the pvp table with the username. All the columns joined from pvptable show null, and the kills & deaths that were dynamically generated with the COUNT. Here is the SQL query.

```
SELECT 
  *,
  pvptable.username AS USER,
  COUNT(pvptable.killer) AS kills,
  COUNT(pvptable.username) AS deaths,
  ROUND(
    COUNT(pvptable.killer) / COUNT(pvptable.username),
    2
  ) AS kd 
FROM
  stats AS st 
  LEFT JOIN pvp AS pvptable 
    ON pvptable.killer = "Username" 
    AND pvptable.username = "Username" 
WHERE st.username = "Username" ;
```

Comment: Your join conditions are a little suspicious.

Comment: I would say,
SELECT *, pvptable.username as user, COUNT(pvptable.killer) as kills,
COUNT(pvptable.username) as deaths,
ROUND(COUNT(pvptable.killer) / COUNT(pvptable.username), 2) AS kd FROM stats as st
LEFT JOIN pvp as pvptable ON pvptable.killer=st.username 
WHERE st.username="Username";

Comment: Change your query to this. Edited: "pvptable.killer=st.username" instead of "pvptable.killer="Username"

Comment: You aren't joining to stats.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `where` and `join` conditions:

- You use `join` when you want to relate fields of one table with fields of another table
- You use `where` when you want to filter the data of your tables

So, to make your query work:

```sql
SELECT 
    *, pvptable.username as user, 
    COUNT(pvptable.killer) as kills,
    COUNT(pvptable.username) as deaths,
    ROUND(COUNT(pvptable.killer) / COUNT(pvptable.username), 2) AS kd  
FROM 
    stats as st
    LEFT JOIN pvp as pvptable 
        ON pvptable.killer=st.Username -- Add some other relations if you need them
WHERE 
    st.username="Username";
```

Comment: You need to tweak this to fit your needs... play around a bit with your query until you make it right. The important thing is: don't mix `where` conditions with `join` conditions.

Comment: I still cant get it to work. Ive tried `SELECT 
    *, pvptable.username as user, 
    COUNT(pvptable.killer) as kills,
    COUNT(pvptable.username) as deaths,
    ROUND(COUNT(pvptable.killer) / COUNT(pvptable.username), 2) AS kd  
FROM 
    stats as st
    LEFT JOIN pvp as pvptable 
        ON pvptable.killer=st.Username
        AND pvptable.username=st.Username
WHERE 
    st.username="tacoboboy32";` but its not working. It still shows deaths the same amount as kills.

Comment: Your query is the only one thats worked at all so far. Can somone please fix this to work completely.

Comment: please can you help me out here?

Comment: @user3205106 I suggest you create a sample database on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) and post the link to it. Just a little sample of your data can be enough, and will make further help easier.

Answer (score 0):

Do a join for each stat that you want, then use COUNT(DISINCT id) (assuming id is the unique key of the pvp table), like this:-

```
SELECT st.username as user, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT pvptable_kills.id) as kills,
    COUNT(DISTINCT pvptable_deaths.id) as deaths,
    ROUND(COUNT(DISTINCT pvptable_kills.id) / COUNT(DISTINCT pvptable_deaths.id), 2) AS kd  
FROM stats as st
LEFT OUTER JOIN pvp as pvptable_kills ON pvptable_kills.killer=st.Username
LEFT OUTER JOIN pvp as pvptable_deaths ON pvptable_deaths.username=st.Username
WHERE st.username="Username"
GROUP BY st.username
```